# UAC prompt on application not in secured location

Tags: windows-7, uac

Windows 7 Pro x64
A state agency application that is basically a wrapper around an FTP program is installed in it's own folder off the root of C:
Win7 has suddenly begun to require elevated privileges to run this program.
The UAC settings in GPO are defaults for Win7Pro. UAC slider is at default.
I looked for entries in Event Viewer at:
Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\UAC\Operational
Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\UAC-FileVirtualization \Operational
No entries in either.
Questions:
1. Any clue why Win7 might have begun requiring elevated privileges?
   i.e. a recent patch? I couldn't find anything, but the month is young.
2. How can I turn on logging of UAC events with sufficient detail to understand what is triggering it?

Comment: Open the Properties dialog for the executable and check the "Compatibility" tab.

Comment: In desperation, I tried XP compatibility, to no avail. I really don't expect it's about platform. I also tried Run as Admin (for all users) - which I don't like doing - and that didn't get it, either.

Comment: The first step is to make sure that "Run as Admin" is turned *off* and that no other compatibility settings are configured.  Also make sure that the application has a manifest with requestedExecutionLevel set to AsInvoker.  I think there might be settings in the registry, too, but I'm not familiar with the details; you'd be better off asking at Super User about that.  Does the problem occur on every Windows 7 machine, or just a particular one?